# Centering a table that is aligned left

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table

I have the following looking table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qJAT.png

with an array like so

```
Array
(
[0] => Name
[1] => Status
[2] => Name
[3] => Status
....
```

and with the following code

```
$i = 0;
$counter = 1;
$split = 0;
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
if($split >= 10) {
    echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />";
    $split = 0;
}
if(++$counter % 2 === 0) {
    echo "<table style='float: left'>";
    echo "<tr><td class='value'>Name</td></tr>";
} else {
    echo "<tr><td class='value'>Status</td></tr>";
    $change = 'Error';
    if (isset($_SESSION['old_value'][$i])) {
    $change = ($value - $_SESSION['old_value'][$i]);
        if ($change >= 10) {
            echo "<tr><td class='update'>".$change."</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            $split++;
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td class='value'>".$change."</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            $split++;
        }
    } else {
        echo "<td class='value'>0</td>";
    }
    $_SESSION['old_value'][$i] = $value;
}
}
```

My question is how can I make the whole table (in the image) aligned center of the page without breaking the 10x7 grid? I tried some css to align it with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$i = 0;
$counter = 1;
$split = 0;
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
if($split >= 10) {
    echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />";
    $split = 0;
}
if(++$counter % 2 === 0) {
    echo "<div style='width:100%; text-align:center;'>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td class='value'>Name</td></tr>";
} else {
    echo "<tr><td class='value'>Status</td></tr>";
    $change = 'Error';
    if (isset($_SESSION['old_value'][$i])) {
    $change = ($value - $_SESSION['old_value'][$i]);
        if ($change >= 10) {
            echo "<tr><td class='update'>".$change."</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "</div>";
            $split++;
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td class='value'>".$change."</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "</div>";
            $split++;
        }
    } else {
        echo "<td class='value'>0</td>";
    }
    $_SESSION['old_value'][$i] = $value;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you but not working with my code. I'm a bit confused. It makes a 1x70 grid like this http://i.imgur.com/xN9S495.png

Answer (score 0):

Give the table a property of `margin: 0 auto`. The 10x7 grid will remain unaffected.

**EDIT**

Considering that the original problem uses multiple tables rather than one large one, I edited the below to support centering all tables inside of a container `div`.

```css
body { width: 100% }
table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; }

.centered-table { display: inline-block; }
.container      { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="centered-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet seems to work but not with my code. http://i.imgur.com/xN9S495.png Centered yes but 1x70 grid. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I'm reading your code... are you generating a new table for each "Name / Status / Value" etc box?

Comment: Looks like I am. That doesn't seem to matter though, even when I have <div> and <table> outside the loop and create just one table the end result is the same as in the picture.

Comment: @DxDogo Edited my original post to center multiple tables. Does this work for you?